# What does the output of the correlation look like in the typical experiments testing Bell inequalities when using light and polarizers?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, epr-experiment

I am curious to know what a plot of polarizer angle vs counts produces for experimental results of Bell tests vs the classical prediction.

Answer (score 3):

You can't go too wrong by looking at the OG Bell's inequality test:

> [Experimental Test of Bell's Inequalities Using Time-Varying Analyzers.](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.49.1804) Alain Aspect, Jean Dalibard, and Gérard Roger.  Phys. Rev. Lett. **49**, 1804 (1982).

Figure 4 from that paper looks like this:

[image]

Note that there is not one particular "classical prediction" to compare this to (which is why the plot only shows the quantum prediction.) Rather, Bell's inequality says that the correlations between various measurements must satisfy certain inequalities if local hidden variables exist.  Different hidden-variables models would presumably produce different predictions, each obeying Bell's inequality.  Aspect, Dalibard, & Roger found that their results were incompatible
with this inequality (see the top of p. 1807 in the linked paper.)

Answer (score 0):

The law of Malus looks remarkably like Michael Seifert's graphic from Aspect et al.  Bell's assumptions excluded wave theory, therefore it has never been considered as a classical contender. All the recent experimental tests **approximate** the law of Malus and the quantum prediction. the the law of Malus and the quantum prediction are identical.

Comment: I have authored a peer reviewed critique of Alain Aspects work but it does not have a DOI, and would be considered "self promotion" here at SE.  Having said that it is a good experiment that duplicates the law of Malus quite well if you include a little attenuation in the polarizers etc. Therefore agreeing with classical wave theory but rejecting  both QM and classical particle theory. QM using the controversial "spooky action at a distance" concept of "entanglement" also agrees with Aspects approximate sinusoid (error bars not quite fitting the curve), but good enough.

Comment: If Aspect et al had used a beam splitter instead of a Q entangled source the result would be the same.  The late Caroline Thompson suggested this to Anton Zieilinger, of transportation fame, but he refused.